# ng-grid click edit to open pop-up

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I've a ng-grid which has Edit, and Delete buttons at the bottom of the grid.

On clicking the Edit button, I want it to open a Modal pop-up with info. from selected rows shown in the modal.

This is my HTML.

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"><!--ng-grid-->
</div>
<button ng-click="??" ng-  disabled="!singleSelection()">Edit</button>
<button ng-click="??" ng-disabled="disabled">Delete</button>
```

And my JS is as follows:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'scheduleData.scheduleList',
            columnDefs: [
                { field: 'id', displayName: 'ID', visible: false },
                { field: 'disabled', displayName: 'Enabled', cellFilter: 'checkmark' }
                { field: 'dpName', displayName: 'Description' },
                { field: 'dpType', displayName: 'Type' },
                { field: 'dpProtection', displayName: 'Protection' },
                { field: 'doProtectionParam', displayName: 'DP Protection Paramters', visible: false },
                { field: 'startDate', displayName: 'Start Date', visible: false, cellFilter: 'date:\'M/d/yy h:mm a\'' },
                { field: 'endDate', displayName: 'End Date', visible: false, cellFilter: 'date:\'M/d/yy h:mm a\'' },
                { field: 'recurrenceType', displayName: 'Recurrence' },
                { field: 'everyNth', displayName: 'Estimated Duration', visible: false },
            enableCellSelection: false,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableColumnResize: true,
            enableColumnReordering: true,
            showColumnMenu: true,
            showFilter: true,
            showFooter: true,
            enableRowselection: true,
            multiSelect: true,
            selectedItems: $scope.selections

            };
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using AngularUI modal to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to working making the foll. change to HTML

```
 <button ng-click="openModal(selections[0])" ng-  disabled="disableButtons(selections)">Edit</button>
```

And in my JS,

```
          $scope.openModal = (selections) => {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'link to URL',
                controller:RelatedController,
                resolve: {
                    schedule: function () {
                        return selections.id == null ? selections : selections.clone();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```